# Почему поменяли адрес меты?

Tags: обсуждение

Раньше было `meta.ru.stackoverflow.com`, сейчас `ru.meta.stackoverflow.com`.

Конечно, это не проблема, просто любопытно.

Comment: там что-то с сертификатами было связано, когда переходили на https

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Это рациональный ход, чтобы минимизировать возню с сертификатами в случаях, когда нужно добавить новые домены (при запуске нового сообщества, скажем). Произошёл в процессе переезда всея SE на HTTPS.

В одном сертификате постарались охватить "практически всё, что потребуется", среди них:

```
*.stackexchange.com
*.meta.stackexchange.com
*.stackoverflow.com
*.meta.stackoverflow.com
```

Наличие таких wildcard'ов в сертификате позволяет запускать новые сообщества SE и новые локализации SO, а также их Меты, совершенно не трогая сертификат.

Для предыдущей схемы (когда адрес Меты образовывался добавлением сегмента `meta.` в начало) это было фактически нереально, т. к. wildcard (шаблон на "что угодно") у домена в сертификате должен быть на месте первого сегмента, и не больше одного. Ну, не то чтобы **должен**, но попытки пойти против этого могут встретить проблемы с совместимостью там и сям.